# Is it safe to publish some internal IP of my company?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when asking networking questions on StackExchange I want to publish some output where several internal IP adresses from my company appear (output of traceroute command for example).

Since I know it is easy to link my StackExchange account to the company I work for, I was wondering if those IP adresses could be used by attackers to infiltrate my company's network.

Comment: Uh that sounds like a terrible idea to publish sensitive information.  What aspect of the output makes it hard to remove them?  Generally text editors have easy ways of removing them (like block selecting).

Comment: The thing is I'm not sure wether it is sensitive information or not

Comment: If your worried about it, then don't do it. The text of your questions shouldn't be so large that you can't strip those out fairly easily, and there can't be *that* many of your questions where the bits that initialise / store the hard-coded IP addresses would be part of a good MCVE.

Comment: Absolutely.  That won't stop someone from your company seeing it and freaking out, however.

Comment: Obscurity should never be the only measure to prevent information from being revealed or from (fire-) walls not to be scaled. If a traceroute would reveal a hole in the (fire)wall, that exists anyway, some attacker will find it and use it to get in. Not publishing the traceroute should not make you feel safe.

Comment: Its not StackOverflow's decision. Why are you posting it on Meta?

Comment: @jakedimds I don't think all questions on Meta have to be related do StackOverflow's decision, there's some questions like "How do I write a good question" and stuff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you don't know it's sensitive, assume that it is.**  It is simply not worth losing your job over a question on Stack Overflow.

As a general rule of thumb, avoid verbatim copy-and-paste of information that is internal to your project; there's no harm in generifying information.  If the question you've written requires more concrete information, faking out the actual values (but providing enough information that the scenario can be replicated) would be the most ideal thing to do.

Comment: I think Imma follow your advice. I guess the question eventually isn't that relevant, because I'm exagerating the efforts it takes to generifying the data. But I was curious to know wether exposing some IP adresses was of any use for potential attackers :)

Comment: ***Yes.***  I recall some poor bloke actually posted not only the IP address of a database server, but full credentials to it.  Luckily it was removed in short order but there are less honorable people that would have taken information like that and kept mum about it.

Comment: @Makoto There's a pretty big difference between an extranet IP address plus full credentials and an internal IP address with no credentials.  The former is everything you need to access the DB, the latter requires 1) getting into the intranet 2) getting credentials to the DB.  It's like having someone's apartment number without even knowing what city they live in, versus having someones full address and a key to their house.

Comment: @Servy:  I'm aware of the differences.  However, the main point here is to not post any information that they may suspect is sensitive to the Internet.

Comment: @Makoto By that logic one shouldn't ever post anything, ever.

Comment: @Servy:  Notwithstanding my personal opinion about how much information makes its way to the Internet that people don't want to...my point is more focused on the corporate environment.  In all honesty there's nothing stopping them from talking to their direct supervisor about it and seeing if it's okay to post content like that, and that permission trumps a lot of what I'm saying here (they'd likely OK it with constraints or outright disallow it).

Answer (score 2):

Makoto gave some great general advice, which would be wise to follow. I wouldn't post the IP's directly, just replace them with generic reserved addresses and make sure you indicate the bitmask.

E.g. it's fine to just substitute with x.x.x.x, but if routing *itself* could be part of the problem, then just use 192.168.1.0/24 for instance, or 10.92.1.117/32 (or just indicate the network clearly).

It's *hard* to post questions about routing without showing the actual addresses, but as long as you replicate the actual setup, you can generally get your point across.

I've done this by just composing in a text file and running it through sed prior to posting to match and replace the actual internal addresses.